# Testlink-Track Integration issue

Tags: trac, testlink

I have done the following to integrate Testlink with TRAC, but i couldn't able to integrate.
Testlink version - 1.9.9(lone ranger)
TRAC version - 0.12.5

I have edited the /var/www/testlink/cfg/trac.cfg.php file:

```
/** Trac Project Root */
define('BUG_TRACK_DB_HOST', 'http://172.16.9.137/trac/');
define('BUG_TRACK_XMLRPC_HOST', 'http://admin:admin@172.16.9.137');

/** @var array Mapping TL test project name vs trac project url */
$g_interface_bugs_project_name_mapping = array(
     'Expresso' => 'expresso',
);
```

and then edited the Edit /var/www/testlink/custom_config.inc.php file and added:

```
<?php
     $g_interface_bugs = 'TRAC';
?>
```

then i was asked to edit the Edit /var/www/testlink/lib/bugtracking/int_trac.php file and replace:

```
$this->xmlrpcClient = new IXR_Client($this->dbHost . '/xmlrpc');
by
$this->xmlrpcClient = new IXR_Client(BUG_TRACK_XMLRPC_HOST);
```

but i couldn't find **/bugtracking/int_trac.php**
I followed the steps from "http://lfestivalet.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/part-5-testlink-trac-integration/"
what is the correct way to integrate testlink 1.9.9 with TRAC 0.12.5?

Answer (score 0):

The guide you are following is probably out of date.  I recommend using the [official TestLink documentation](https://gitorious.org/testlink-ga/testlink-documentation/source/fa5463dc53c1ed0ac8d830149b64e94e7ad499a4%3aend-users/1.9) instead.  The installation manual doesn't mention anything about a "int_trac.php" file in the Trac integration instructions.  It's possible that what you see on the blog is a hack to work around a bug that has since been fixed (the blog post is over a year old).  Try a fresh install using the latest versions of Trac and TestLink and follow sections 30-32 in the TestLink installation manual.  You should have more success that way.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the integration working today but it took a couple of tweaks.  As bta has stated, the instructions you followed are out of date.  With 1.9.9 you just need to click on the 'Issue Tracker Management' link on the 'Desktop' and then hit 'Create'.

Copy and paste the Trac configuration example into the Configuration box (and update your settings).

For the URL, you just need the base, and not the full xmlrpc URL.  e.g. https://hostname.com/trac/ProjectName

Remember to activate the bug tracker for your project.

The problem I found was that either the 'Create new bug' or 'Assign bug' functionality worked, but not both depending on whether I had `https://hostname.com/trac/ProjectName` or `https://hostname.com/trac/ProjectName/login` as the URL.

I fixed this by modifying testlink/lib/issuetrackerintegration/tracxmlrpcInterface.class.php to replace:

> $this->cfg->urixmlrpc = $base . 'xmlrpc';

with

> $this->cfg->urixmlrpc = $base . 'login/xmlrpc';

YMMV vary with this as it may depend whether you allow anonymous login (we don't).